# How to: Pandas group by A, B and plot group A in one figure with each line of group B

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, multiline

I try to figure a way out with pandas, where I can plot my data. First I want to group them by category, and then I want to group them by Model. In my Table I record the price on each day (timestamp).

And what I want to compare is, how the price change over time for the models, but within each category.

So I want a figure for Cars, Bikes, etc.., where I only plot the related price line

Example Table

```
#  Timestamp    Category    Model     Price
1  2020-05-01   Cars        BMW M1    12000€
2  2020-05-01   Cars        Audi A8   43000€
3  2020-05-01   Bikes       Benelli   5000€
3  2020-05-01   Bikes       Honda     9000€
```

At the moment, I do this:

```
df.groupby(['Category', 'Model' ]).plot(x = "Timestamp", y = "Price")
```

But this plots for each model a separet figure.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

## [Edited]

I try to put make an python example, so you guys could get the data.
In this example, we have stock price and Market Categories.

Basically, I want to plot the stock price of each company of category Q in one figure, and category O in another figure. And if there are more categories, plot the companies in other figures.

This way, you could compare one company of the same category against each other

```py
import pandas as pd
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import seaborn as sns
# import numpy as np
# import plotly 
# import cufflinks as cf
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
# import time
import requests
import io

# cf.go_offline()

url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/nasdaq-listings/nasdaq-listed_csv/data/7665719fb51081ba0bd834fde71ce822/nasdaq-listed_csv.csv"

s = requests.get(url).content
companies = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))[:5]

Symbols = companies['Symbol'].tolist()
Category = companies['Market Category'].tolist()
display(Symbols)
gr=  companies.groupby('Market Category')


stock_final = pd.DataFrame()
# iterate over each symbol
start = datetime.datetime(2020,9,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)

for i in Symbols:  
    # print the symbol which is being downloaded
    print( str(Symbols.index(i)) + str(' : ') + i, sep=',', end=',', flush=True)  
    index = Symbols.index(i)
    try:
        # download the stock price 
        stock = []
        stock = yf.download(i,start=start, end=end, progress=False)
        
        # append the individual stock prices 
        if len(stock) == 0:
            None
        else:
            stock['Name']=i
            stock['Market Category'] = Category[index]
            stock_final = stock_final.append(stock,sort=False)
    except Exception:
        None

groups = stock_final.groupby(['Market Category', 'Name'])
groups.head()
```

## Solution

I've ended up doing it in two for loops:

```py
for name, group in  df.groupby(['Market Category']):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for key, grp in group.groupby('Name'):
        ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x='timestamp', y='price', label=key)
    
    plt.title(name)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: do you mean you want all graphs in one figure?

Comment: can you post a copy-and-pasteable example please?

Comment: @Alex, this example did not work for me, I have updated the problem description with an python script.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, I have posted an pythonscript, which you should be able to run with example data

Comment: @JanWilamowski, I meant to plot each category in a figure. Another category should be plotted into another figure

Comment: This example is huge, could you just post the part which creates the dataframe? E.g. print out `stock_final.to_dict()`, and then just include that in your example

Comment: This is not the desired form, but it is an easy output. `groups.plot(y=['Open','High','Low','Close'], kind='line')`